# Regex that counts words but ignores words encased in curly braces

Tags: regex

I am absolutely horrible with regex and avoid it when i can, however i can but this seems suitable for a bit of regex.
What i am interested in is counting the number of words in a string excluding words encased in {}

Example:

input : someting test whatever {not} and also {not you}
output : someting test whatever and also

My best try was

```
\w+(?![^{}]*})
```

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for matching open/close patterns. You would have to hold state somewhere whether a brace was opened while you parse for words separated by spaces. Can't do that with regex.

Comment: What is the programming language/regex flavor?

Comment: doing this in nodejs/javascript

Comment: there was a good answer yesterday someone posted and wanted to accept that answer, but i could not since i had to wait 10 mins, and that answer was removed in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

You can match braces remove them using javascript. Just note, like cyberbrain's comment, this won't be robust for many nested braces.

```js
    const p = 'someting test whatever {not} and also {not you}'

    const regex = /{.*?}/g;
    console.log(p.replace(regex, ''));
    // expected output: "someting test whatever  and also"
```

Note the double-space in the output, because `{not}` is removed but not the spaces around it.

To explain the regex:

- The `/`s are the regex's delimiters.
- The `g` at the end is a [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global), indicating the replace should act on every match in the input string, not just the first match.
- `.*?`:

  - `.` means any character
  - `*?` means to match any 0 or more of what came before it, but the `?` makes it "lazy", meaning it'll return the shortest match found.